# Choose company with most records mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with records from different companies. I need to select records from companies which have the most, second most and third most records and plot their number of records per year. How do I select them?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

The table would look something like this:

```
Company    Year
A          1999
A          1999
B          1999
C          1999
A          2000
C          2000
A          2003
```

So if I select the company with the most records, A has the most records, and the output is;

```
Year    Total
1999     2
2000     1
2003     1
```

And for the company with second most records, the output is ( in this case, company C)

```
Year    Total
1999     1
2000     1
```

Third most will be company B.

Comment: Can you give your table structure, some example data and the expected output for this data?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say something like

```
SELECT company,COUNT(company) AS rec,year
FROM your_table GROUP BY company, year ORDER BY rec DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: hmm.. how do I select only the company with the most records, to draw a graph chart of it's record growth over the year? and also, the second most records, etc

Comment: Run the query above, return the data, and then for the top three results, run a select * (although obviously not using *) against that company id...

Comment: can that be automated? I would like to put the query into a php script and have the script produce the relevant charts immediately (seperate scripts for most, 2nd and 3rd)

Comment: use the SQL to get the data you need, then use each row of data as input to your charting script to produce the 3 charts you need.

Comment: i tried the SQL, it gave something like:

Company | rec |year
A       |  5  | 2008
B       |  10 | 2008
C       |  2  | 2008

I need it to determine which company has the most, 2nd most, and 3rd most data, then produce a trend data which show , for each company, the number of records per year.

Answer (score 0):

most_frequent:

```
SELECT year, COUNT(year) AS total FROM your_table 
WHERE company = 
    (SELECT company, COUNT(company) AS c
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY c
     ORDER BY c DESC
     LIMIT 0,1)
```

second most:

```
SELECT year, COUNT(year) AS total FROM your_table 
WHERE company = 
    (SELECT company, COUNT(company) AS c
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY c
     ORDER BY c DESC
     LIMIT 1,1)
```

third most:

```
SELECT year, COUNT(year) AS total FROM your_table 
WHERE company = 
    (SELECT company, COUNT(company) AS c
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY c
     ORDER BY c DESC
     LIMIT 2,1)
```

In order to get two dimensional output in one query:

```
SELECT company, year, COUNT(year) AS total FROM your_table 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT company, COUNT(company) AS c
     FROM your_table
     GROUP BY c
     ORDER BY c DESC) AS t1
ON your_table.company = t1.company
ORDER BY t1.c DESC
```

I'm sorry, I haven't tested it. Just leave a comment if you have any trouble.

Comment: looks good; 

i did a query to get the top 3, by using limit 0,3, putting them into an array, then running SELECT based on the elements in the array for all the three.